# Посоветуйте хороший локальный сервачок

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Сейчас нет ни времени, ни желания ставить по отдельности(Apache, mySql + phpMyAdmin, php).
Посоветуйте что ни будь путное кроме **Vertigo** и **Denwer**.
Спасибо!

Comment: просто ради повышения образованности: чем эти двое не угодили?

Comment: Денвер мне просто не нравится) Ну незнаю, он гадит всю систему.
А Вертриго, не ставится. Кидает ошибку типа: NSIS Error

Comment: А portable версию пробовали ставить?
Ведь Денвер делает всего две "гадящие" вещи: изменяет hosts(можно запретить и править вручную) и добавляет виртуальный диск(можно так же запретить и лезть в /webservers/home/)

Comment: Особенно виртуальный диск напрягает)
Да я знаю что можно запретить, но хочется что то другое.

Comment: IIS еще ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте Open Server(open-server.ru)

Answer (score 1):

Denwer имеют функцию vhost, там можно создавать несколько виртуальных хостов(типа: test.ru), удобно писать сайты будто они уже у хостера. У Vertrigo создание вертуальных хостов нету, думаю это их единственное отличия и конечно версии php, mysql и Apach. Но думаю это дело привычки я например использую vertrigo. Думаю все зависит от твоей цели.

XAMPP и AppServ по ним комментов нету, так как не пользовался.

Comment: путное КРОМЕ Vertigo и Denwer

Comment: есть XAMPP и AppServ только по ним нечего сказать не могу потому, что не пользовался.

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP норм тема, почему денвер не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Я за AppServ двумя руками